# Reverse has_many with polymorphism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphism

I have two models:  Users and Projects.  The idea is that Users can follow both projects AND other users.  Naturally, Users and Projects are part of a polymorphic "followable" type.  Now, using the user model, I'd like to get three things:

```
user.followed_users
user.followed_projects
user.followers
```

The first two work fine; It's the third that I'm having trouble with.  This is sort of a reverse lookup where the foreign key becomes the "followable_id" column in the follows table, but no matter how I model it, I can't get the query to run correctly.

User Model

```
has_many :follows, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :followed_projects, :through => :follows, :source => :followable, :source_type => "Project"
has_many :followed_users, :through => :follows, :source => :followable, :source_type => "User"
has_many :followers, :through => :follows, :as => :followable, :foreign_key => "followable", :source => :user, :class_name => "User"
```

Follow Model

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :followable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My follows table has:
 user_id
 followable_id
 followable_type

Whenever I run the query I get:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `follows` ON `users`.`id` = `follows`.`user_id` WHERE `follows`.`user_id` = 7
```

where it should be "followable_id = 7 AND followable_type = 'User", not "user_id = 7"

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out.  Took a look at a [sample project Michael Hartl made](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/app/models/user.rb) and noticed that the correct way to do this is to specify not only a relationship table (in this case follows) but also a reverse relationship table (which I called reverse follows).

```
    has_many    :follows,
                        :dependent => :destroy

    has_many    :followed_projects,
                        :through => :follows,
                        :source => :followable,
                        :source_type => "Project"

    has_many    :followed_users,
                        :through => :follows,
                        :source => :followable,
                        :source_type => "User"

    has_many    :reverse_follows,
                        :as => :followable,
                        :foreign_key => :followable_id,
                        :class_name => "Follow"

    has_many    :followers,
                        :through => :reverse_follows,
                        :source => :user
```

Hope this helps some people out down the line!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to explicitly spell out the foreign key. You have:

```
:foreign_key => "followable"
```

you need:

```
:foreign_key => "followable_id"
```

full code:

```
has_many :followers, :through => :follows, :as => :followable, :foreign_key => "followable_id", :source => :user, :class_name => "User"
```

Comment: Nope, Rails automatically appends "_id" if you don't include it.  I just tried it for good measure and still no luck